# "That" vs "those" with multiple singular nouns

Tags: grammatical-number

I just received an email citing my contact info and asking me to confirm it.

I replied with "Those address and phone number are correct."

The Gmail grammar checker underlined "address" and "number". Should I have used "That" instead of "Those"? That didn't seem better to me. Two singular things make a plural, right?

Comment: The contact information you have is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that "address and phone number" are plural, but "those" is not correct here.
"That address and phone number are correct." is correct, and is the same as saying "That address and that phone number are correct."

There are similar situations where you could use "those". For example,
"Those, the address and phone number, are correct."